# AS3 library for Socket.io

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, socket.io

I'm using node.js+socket.io in my projects, and one of the issues that bothers me the most is absence of normal AS3 library than can handle communications between as3 and node.js using socket.io.

In my last project, I used https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO this library, but I had to roll back to node.js v0.8.25.

So - requirements:

- Works with node.js v0.10.x
- Works with socket.io v0.9.x
- Secure connection support (wss)

It would be nice to have more than one library, maybe someone knows a better one?
Thanks!

Comment: Good question.  I looked into this a bit a while back, and ended up writing a separate protocol for the Flash clients that 1) shared JSON messages between Flash clients and socket.io clients, and 2) allowed Flash clients to send binary AMF serializations to each other (not really javascript compatible).

Answer (score 3):

I also needed this, so here's what I used: https://github.com/sinnus/socket.io-flash.

```
requires Socket.IO(>= v.0.8)
```

Comment: Will node.js and socket.io not work with Flash "out-of-the-box?" I've tried implementing it with regular AS3 XMLSockets and I can make an an initial connection in the client SWF, but the io.sockets.on('connection') never fires and the SWF can't send() from a socket.

Comment: Maybe with some javascript facade which you're calling using ExternalInterface.. I've not tried it, these libraries if still supported should be ok though

Comment: Ah, I see. These are stand-alone SWFs/projectors, so that might also have something to do with it.